# Issue with transparent texture on 3D primitive, XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I need to draw a large set of cubes, all with (possibly) unique textures on each side. Some of the textures also have parts of transparency. The cubes that are behind ones with transparent textures should show through the transparent texture. However, it seems that the order in which I draw the cubes decides if the transparency works or not, which is something I want to avoid. Look here:

```
cubeEffect.CurrentTechnique = cubeEffect.Techniques["Textured"];

Block[] cubes = new Block[4];
cubes[0] = new Block(BlockType.leaves, new Vector3(0, 0, 3));
cubes[1] = new Block(BlockType.dirt, new Vector3(0, 1, 3));
cubes[2] = new Block(BlockType.log, new Vector3(0, 0, 4));
cubes[3] = new Block(BlockType.gold, new Vector3(0, 1, 4));


foreach(Block b in cubes) {
    b.shape.RenderShape(GraphicsDevice, cubeEffect);
}
```

This is the code in the Draw method. It produces this result:
[image: the first image]

As you can see, the textures behind the leaf cube are not visible on the other side. When i reverse index 3 and 0 on in the array, I get this:
[image: correct image]

It is clear that the order of drawing is affecting the cubes. I suspect it may have to do with the blend mode, but I have no idea where to start with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are relying on depth buffering to achieve occlusion.  This technique only works for opaque objects.

To achieve correct occlusion for a scene containing transparent objects:

1. Set DepthBufferEnable and
   DepthBufferWriteEnable to true
2. Draw all opaque geometry
3. Leave DepthBufferEnable set to true,
   but change DepthBufferWriteEnable to
   false
4. Sort alpha blended objects by
   distance from the camera, then draw
   them in order from back to front

Extract from [Depth sorting alpha blended objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects.aspx) by Shawn Hargreaves

Answer (score 1):

Drawing transparent objects properly is harder than regular ones. The reason is when face  is rendered by default it marks all pixels as drawn at certain depth and as result pixels that are behind will not be drawn at all. I'd recommend getting a book on 3d rendering and look through for more details.

The easiest approach you already found - draw transparent objects AFTER non-transparent ones. Works for transpreant and semi-transparent objects. Note that transparent objects need to be sorted to be drawn correctly (unlike non-transparent ones).

In your particular case (non-semitransparent) you can change texture renreding to NOT render anything for transparent parts.

Comment: If you only have objects that are solid or "not solid" then you could maintain two lists and render solid first. Non-solid could then be rendered last with it sorted so you render the furthest object first. If you have objects with a mix of polygons that can be solid/non-solid you might be better to look into implementing some form of multi-pass system where you pass in to your rendering code which pass it is, then you can filter polygons at that point as to whether you render in this pass or not (you'd still need to sort).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this if you don't have semi-transparent pixels on the objects. It'll either render completely solid or won't write to the Z-Buffer.
As in [Riemers Alpha Testing](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding_renderstates.php).

Comment: This would probably work in XNA 3.1, but unfortunately, 4.0 does not support the AlphaTest feature.

Comment: My experience using XNA itself is quite limited currently, however there seems to be a built-in AlphaTestEffect in XNA 4 now, I'm not sure if it exists to make it work across all 3 platforms and hide the magic, or whether you can also get at what it does internally. It might also be enough for your needs right now.

Comment: I discovered the AlphaTestEffect, and tried to use it, but I must have messed up somewhere, because it turned out completely wrong. I'll just draw the transparent blocks after the solid ones.

Answer (score -2):

XNA (and DirectX and all major 3D libraries) take in consideration something called [culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). Although from your code I cannot tell for sure, from the images I think this is your problem. The polygons that you don't see have the vertices in the wrong order. If this is the problem, you have two solutions:

- either turn culling off (`device.RenderState.CullMode = CullMode.None;` if I remember correctly)
- apply your texture twice, with the points of the polygon both in clockwise order and counter clockwise

Comment: I know what culling is, and I don't think it's the problem. As I showed in my examples, by reversing the array indices for the cubes it displays the texture behind, no problem. I think the issue is that the leaf cube is drawn first, and the alpha in that texture is blended with the background (without the other cubes). After that, the other cubes are drawn, but the leaf texture is not blended with those cubes. It's just a theory, but I think it is correct.

Comment: Also, if I move my camera inside the leaf cube, I can see the other cubes' textures.

Comment: I see. Then I think you need to post more of your code, like what does your effect look like and how does the Block initiates and draws the vertices.

Comment: @Andrei Pana - You can find that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674804/drawing-a-textured-cube-with-multiple-sides-in-xna-4-0

Comment: And the effect is the one found in Reimers XNA Tutorials.

Comment: From the images the problem seems to be that the transparent object is rendered first, writing into the depth buffer, after that nothing the graphics card thinks is behind that point will be written to the framebuffer. As another answer pointed out, you need to render all solid first, then render transparent parts last, sorted so that you render them furthest to closest.

Comment: @Roger Perkins - That's sort of what I wanted to avoid... Is there no other solution?

Comment: @Bevin - In the image above you don't actually seem to blend with whats already there, it seems to be all or nothing (solid pixel or completely transparent). If you don't need to blend with pixels underneath, I'm pretty sure you can not write to the Z-Buffer for completely transparent pixels (basically alpha test whether or not to render). In that case the order wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Roger Perkins - What you just said flew right past my head. Do you have any code examples?

Comment: @Bevin I posted an answer with the link to another Riemer sample where he renders pixels only where the alpha value is greater than a certain value. All alpha values lower than it will result in nothing in the frame or depth buffers.