# Firemonkey semi-transparent Image3D is sometimes opaque

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I create a FireMonkey app with 3 semi-transparent tImage3D's.
Here's the code and the screen.  All seems well.

```
procedure TForm1.Form3DCreate(Sender: TObject);

// create a new semi-transparent timage3d
// object with color and Z position.
procedure NewImage ( const nColor : tColor;
                     const nZ     : integer );
begin
  // create the image
  with tImage3D . Create ( self ) do
    begin
      // put it on the screen
      Parent := self;
      // set the size
      Width := 10;
      Height := 10;
      // set the image to a single pixel.
      Bitmap . Width := 1;
      Bitmap . Height := 1;
      // set the Alpha to $80 to make it
      // semi-transparent
      Bitmap . Pixels [ 0, 0 ] := $80000000 + nColor;
      // set the z position
      Position . Z := nZ;
    end;
end;

begin
  NewImage ( claRed,   +10 );
  NewImage ( claGreen,   0 );
  NewImage ( claBlue,  -10 );
end;
```

[image: All is well]

Now reverse the order.  Now they are opaque.

```
begin
  NewImage ( claRed,   -10 );
  NewImage ( claGreen,   0 );
  NewImage ( claBlue,  +10 );
end;
```

[image: Now they are opaque]

What am I missing?

Comment: Apparently an object is only semi-transparent to an object created earlier.  If that makes any sense.  The red box appears pink because you can see the white background though it, but you can't see the green or blue boxes through it.  Through the green box, you can see the white background and the red box, but not the blue box.   I've had the same thing happen with text3d objects as well.

Comment: I think @user is right. Try to redraw the objects in front. If the object is not detecting anything below it, it probably skips blend functions, and the white background doesn't count.

Comment: What do you mean by redraw the objects in front?  This is a very simplified example to illustrate the problem. The original app had several floating spinning images and text, and the position of every object was changed every 50 ms, and so was constantly being redrawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FireMonkey (as of now) doesn’t support rendering semi-transparent objects in 3D.

FireMonkey only supports **blending** of semi-transparent objects (either through the Opacity property or because of their texture, for instance a semi-transparent PNG image), but [blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) alone is not enough to get it right in 3D with a [Z-Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) (which is what FMX, and most 3D apps are using).

For a technical explanation, you can read about [Transparency sorting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting), the article is about OpenGL, but applies to DirectX too.

**So to get correct rendering, you need to have your semi-transparent objects sorted back-to-front from the camera's point of view**.

You can get more details and some code in this post to work-around the issue:

[Rendering semi-transparent object in FireMonkey](http://delphitools.info/2011/11/04/rendering-semi-transparent-objects-in-firemonkey/)

**but keep in mind it'll just be a workaround**.

Ideally this should be handled by the FireMonkey scene-graph, as it is rendering-dependent, otherwise, you end up having to change the scene-graph structure, which can have various other side-effects, and is even more problematic if you have more than one camera looking at the same scene.

Also, the sorting approach will only work with convex objects that don’t intersect, and for which you don’t have triple-overlap, as in:

[image: Triple Overlap example]

For which there exists no correct sorting (none of the elements is in front of the others).

Answer (score 0):

As you already discovered you have to draw transparent objects from back to front.

When drawing a transparent object, the object is drawn, and blended with the pixels that are behind it.

So this happens when you draw from back to front:
You draw the red image, it is blended with the white background. You can tell by the "pink" instead of pure red colour that it is blended with the white background. Then you draw the green image, it is blended with the already drawn white background and red image. Finally you draw the blue image, which is blended with the already drawn objects.

But now we draw from front to back:
We draw the red plane first. It is blended with the white background which you can see because it is pink instead of red. Now we draw the green plane. It is blended with the white background, you can tell by the colour, it is not pure, deep, green. But, the renderer sees that a part falls behind the red plane, so it doesn't draw that part. But, you think: the red plane is transparent, the renderer should draw behind that red plane! Well no, the renderer only keeps track of the depth / z-order of the pixels in the z-buffer / depth-buffer, it doesn't know if that pixel is transparent or not. The same story goes for the blue plane, only the part that is not obscured by other objects is drawn.

What is this depth buffer you speak of?
In the depth-buffer the depth of every pixel is stored. When you draw a pixel at 2,2 with a z of 1, the depth-buffer at 2,2 is updated with the value 1. Now when you draw a line from 1,2 to 3,2 with a z of 3, the renderer will only draw the pixels where the depth-buffer has a value of >= 3. So pixel 1,2 is drawn (and the depth-buffer at 1,2 set to 3). Pixel 2,2 is not drawn, because the depth-buffer indicates that that pixel is already drawn with a lesser depth (1 vs 3). Pixel 3,2 is drawn and the depth-buffer at 3,2 is set to 3.
So the depth-buffer is used to keep track of the z-order of every pixel to prevent overwriting that pixel with a pixel that is farther away.

If you want to draw transparent objects the right way, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683030/issue-with-transparent-texture-on-3d-primitive-xna-4-0).

Excerpt from that answer:

- First draw opaque objects.
- Disable depth-buffer writes (so the depth-buffer is not updated), but keep depth-buffer checking enabled.
- Draw transparent objects. Because the depth-buffer is not updated you don't have the problem of transparent objects obscuring each other. Because depth-buffer checking is enabled, you don't draw behind opaque objects.

I don't know if FireMonkey supports disabling depth-buffer writes, you have to find out yourself.