# XNA transparent textures rendering issue

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, transparency, alpha

There used to be one or two questions with this issuse before, but I can no longer find them, so here I go.

When rendering models that have partially transparent textures using BasicEffect the basic solution is to sort everything by distance from the camera and then draw them from back to front in order to get the correct image. However when the models cross each other part of the closer one will fall behind the other and the transparency will render incorrectily.

Example:

[image: Render issue]

Both intersecting items there are just a rectangular model with a texture.
Since the game will eventually contain indicators that have to have more 3 dimensional shapes and will have to cross other objects, this is a big issue for me and I cannot find a solution.

Help please. Thank you,

zoliking

EDIT: It's pretty basic, but for the sake of completeness here's the drawing code (minus unrelevant fluff):

```
private void sortDrawables()
        {
        float[] distances = new float[drawables.Length];

        for (int i=0; i<drawables.Length; i++)
            {
            if (drawables[i] is Character)
                {
                distances[i] = Vector3.Distance(cameraPosition, ((Character) drawables[i]).marker.position);
                }
                else if (drawables[i] is FixObject)
                {
                distances[i] = Vector3.Distance(cameraPosition, ((FixObject) drawables[i]).marker.position);
                }
                else if (drawables[i] is PositionSpike)
                {
                distances[i] = Vector3.Distance(cameraPosition, ((PositionSpike) drawables[i]).position);
                }
            }

        for (int i=0; i<drawables.Length; i++)
            {
            int largestIndex = i;
            float largestDistance = -1f;

            for (int j=i; j<drawables.Length; j++)
                {
                if (drawables[j] is Character)
                    {
                    if (Vector3.Distance(((Character) drawables[j]).marker.position, cameraPosition) > largestDistance)
                        {
                        largestDistance = Vector3.Distance(((Character) drawables[j]).marker.position, cameraPosition);
                        largestIndex = j;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (drawables[j] is FixObject)
                    {
                    if (Vector3.Distance(((FixObject) drawables[j]).marker.position, cameraPosition) > largestDistance)
                        {
                        largestDistance = Vector3.Distance(((FixObject) drawables[j]).marker.position, cameraPosition);
                        largestIndex = j;
                        }
                    }
                }

            float tempDistance = distances[i];
            distances[i] = distances[largestIndex];
            distances[largestIndex] = tempDistance;

            Object tempCharacter = drawables[i];
            drawables[i] = drawables[largestIndex];
            drawables[largestIndex] = tempCharacter;
            }
        }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        sb.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in board.Meshes)
            {
            foreach (BasicEffect be in mesh.Effects)
                {
                UniversalLighting.MatchEffect(be);

                be.View = view;
                be.Projection = projection;
                be.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                }
            mesh.Draw();
            }

        sortDrawables();

        foreach (Object c in drawables)
            {
            if (c is Character)
                {
                ((Character) c).Draw(projection, view, cameraPosition, animMatrix, sources);
                }
                else if (c is FixObject)
                {
                ((FixObject) c).Draw(projection, view, cameraPosition, sources, Matrix.Identity);
                }
                else if (c is PositionSpike)
                {
                ((PositionSpike) c).Draw(projection, view, orangePixel);
                }
            }
```

And the drawing code the Character and FixObject classes call:

```
public void Draw(Matrix projection, Matrix view, Texture2D texture, Texture2D[] frontLights, Texture2D[] backLights, LightSource[] sources, GraphicsDevice gd, Vector3 cameraPosition, Matrix animMatrix, float rotation = 0f, Texture2D otherSide = null)
        {
        foreach (ModelMesh m in model.Meshes)
            {
            foreach (BasicEffect be in m.Effects)
                {
                UniversalLighting.MatchEffect(be);

                be.TextureEnabled = true;
                be.Texture = texture;

                be.View = view;
                be.Projection = projection;
                be.World =  Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(stretch.X*-1, stretch.Y*-1, 1)) *
                            Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation) *
                            animMatrix *
                            Matrix.CreateTranslation(position - new Vector3(0, stretch.Y/-2*MODEL_SIZE, 0) + rotNormal * 0.0005f * orderify);
                }
            m.Draw();
            }

        if (otherSide != null)
            {
            foreach (ModelMesh m in model.Meshes)
                {
                foreach (BasicEffect be in m.Effects)
                    {
                    UniversalLighting.MatchEffect(be);

                    be.TextureEnabled = true;
                    be.Texture = otherSide;

                    be.View = view;
                    be.Projection = projection;
                    be.World =  Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(stretch.X, stretch.Y*-1, 1)) *
                                Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation + (float) Math.PI * 2) *
                                animMatrix *
                                Matrix.CreateTranslation(position - new Vector3(0, stretch.Y/-2*MODEL_SIZE, 0) + rotNormal * -0.0005f * orderify);
                    }
                m.Draw();
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit 2: So I just found an article that goes as far as to address this problem as not solvable by sorting (duh), but there has to be some sort of rendering trickery to allow this. Graphics applications render situations like this in their editor windows in real time, any 3D particle effects using flat models with textures have to deal with this.

Basically all that needs to be done is to detect where conflicting pixels are (as in something has to be drawn behind an object with transparency already drawn) and in the overlapping area do a slower, ray based approach to determine the pixel color. I'd be happy to write this manually if there is nothing built in, but I don't know how to get into the details of rendering.

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote or thought XNA. Maybe unrelated, but might contain some useful insight - seems to employ some trickery and has to do with transparency... Not object collision though, as far as I can tell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687807/8695782

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve this. As long as my models don't cross I have no problems, and that's a presupposition in the question/answer you linked.

Comment: I was suspecting that, it was worth a shot in case it did.

Comment: This is why some 'engines' split/tessellate triangles before rendering so crossing triangles get split into non-crossing triangles